# How to stop window.open from refreshing the window in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Lets say you have code like this.

```
function openNewTab(url) {
      const newTab = window.open(url, 'windowNameHehe');
};
```

Now every time you call this function it will open a new tab. However, if the window is already opened it will go to it and refresh/reload it. How do I stop it from reloading/refreshing and just bringing it to view? 
Doing something like newTab.focus() or adding the boolean (true/false) in the 4th parameter of window.open isn't working for me either. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

```
function openNewTab(url) {
  var newTab = window.open(url, 'windowNameHehe', , false);
  newTab.focus();
}
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

[Open a URL in a new tab (and not a new window) using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-and-not-a-new-window-using-javascript)

Comment: This doesn't work. The browser will go to that window and refresh it.

Comment: window.open(url, 'windowNameHehe', , false); How about now?

Answer (score 0):

```
function openNewTab(url) {
  const newTab = window.open('', 'windowNameHehe');
  newTab.focus();
  if (!newTab.location.hostname) {
    newTab.location.href = url;
  }
};
```